# How to Button Hidden validation in android?

Tags: android, validation

If Main activity button will be click open Dashboard screen..In this dashboard screen one button will be hide another buttons will be show from validation( usrerole == user ).but i got issue once click on another buttons in dashboard once back to dashboard "hidden" button will be how to rectify this issue?

MainActivity Class:

```
if(userRole.equals("User")){
// String user = "test";
   Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
   i1.putExtra("user",userRole);
   startActivity(i1);
}
```

Dashboard Class:

```
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HrInternalUseOnly.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        final Bundle exe = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (exe != null) {

            String uservalue = exe.getString("user");

            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this,uservalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (uservalue.equals("User")) {

                btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else   if (uservalue.equals("Admin")) {
                btn5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }


        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyProductivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }


        });
```

Comment: Your statement is not clear.Please elaborate

Comment: means when you click on another button next MyProductivity Activity open and when you go back to Dashboard your button is in gone states , So you want to visible hidden button in this case?

Comment: yes correct  chetan

Answer (score 0):

Every time you go back to previous page (Either `Activity` or `Fragment`) the view get recreated so all the states are lost, you can simple save state of `Button` inside bundle like you did in `MainActivity`. Call this code after changing button visibility like this:

```
getIntent().putExtra("isButtonVisible", false);
```

This will also help you retain your view state on Orientation change, so your view will appear the same even after Screen Rotation..

Comment: when i click on another button next MyProductivity Activity open and when me  go back to Dashboard your button is in gone states

Answer (score 0):

Your below code will work only when there are extras in the Intent.So your button 5 will be hidden in the case.
Modify code as below:

```
final Bundle exe = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (exe != null) {

            String uservalue = exe.getString("user");

            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this,uservalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (uservalue.equals("User")) {

                btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

        }
        else
        {
        btn5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: yaa,btn5 will be hidden ..but remaining buttons like btn4 will click open another activity and go back btn5 will be show how to rectify problems

Comment: Ok.
Let me check.

Comment: Are you opening new activity on back press because my button is still hidden if I back press and come back to Dashboard activity

Comment: yaa,,i use navigation button back but it show hidden button also..pls send me ur code

Comment: I am not using any button,I am just coming back from the activity by onBackPressed for now.

Comment: Manifest file :      <activity
            android:name=".MyEmployeeResources"
            android:label="MyEmployeeResources"
            android:parentActivityName=".Dashboard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Dashboard" />
        </activity>

Comment: Dashboard:@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

Comment: btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HrInternalUseOnly.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

Comment: final Bundle exe = getIntent().getExtras();


        if (exe != null) {
            String uservalue = exe.getString("user");
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this,uservalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (uservalue.equals("User")) {

                btn5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }
        else   {
            btn5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

Comment: btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyProductivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }


        });